# storing the longest string after strsplit

Tags: arrays, matlab, strsplit

I am trying to store the longest resultant string after using the function strsplit unable to do so

eg: I have input strings such as 
'R.DQDEGNFRRFPTNAVSMSADENSPFDLSNEDGAVYQRD.L'or
'L.TSNKDEEQRELLKAISNLLD'

I need store the string only between the dots (.)
If there is no dot then I want the entire string.
Each string may have zero, one or two dots.

part of the code which I am using:

```
for i=1:700
    x=regexprep(txt(i,1), '\([^\(\)]*\)','');

    y=(strsplit(char(x),'.'));

    for j=1:3

        yValues(1,j)=y{1,j};
    end
end
```

But the string yValues is not storing the value of y, instead showing the following error:

> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

What am I doing wrong and are there any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked that y has the dimensions that you expect? Is yValues a cell array or a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `y` is a cell array and each element contains *an entire string* and it therefore can't be assigned to a single element in a normal array `yvalues(1,j)`.

You need `yvalues` to be a cell array and then you can assign into it just fine.

```
yValues{j} = y{j};
```

Or more simply

```
% Outside of your loop
yValues = cell(1,3);

% Then inside of your loop
yValues(j) = y(j);
```

Alternately, if you just want the longest output of `strsplit`, you can just do something like this.

```
% Split the string
parts = strsplit(mystring, '.');

% Find the length of each piece and figure out which piece was the longest
[~, ind] = max(cellfun(@numel, parts));

% Grab just the longest part
longest = parts{ind};
```